# jQuery trigger not working after opening/closing facebox

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, facebox

I have a whole heap of checkboxes with an event handler `selectVid`.

`$std_cbs.on('change', selectVid);`

A "toggle all" checkbox toggles all other checkboxes, and triggers the "change" event for those checkboxes.

`$checkboxes.prop('checked', is_checked).trigger('change');`

This works great, until I open and close a [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) popup.  After this when I toggle the "toggle all" checkbox the other checkboxes toggle as well, but their event handler `selectVid` is not called.

If I toggle individual checkboxes, `selectVid` is called as expected.

If I refresh the page everything works again.  I've stepped through with Chrome's debugger, and the line `$checkboxes.prop('checked', is_checked).trigger('change');` is always reached.

So why does `trigger('change')` no longer cause `selectVid` to be called after the facebox popup has been opened and closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by accident by using the Self-Executing Anonymous Functions pattern, as explained in [this article](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/).

I assume there must have been a naming conflict when I opened facebox, which was resolved once I put all my functions and members in their own namespace (using the aforementioned pattern).